# KDB+ using or with where and like

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I am trying to get information from column_1 and column_2 for apptype CASPER and FOO. 
The script works fine when I search for just one or the other apptype. 
However, when use the 'or' statement to include both apptypes in one output, I get an error. 
I think it is just the 'kdb or' statement.

I don't have a KDB reference manual.

```
raze{[tradedate] 

setdate tradedate;

`rootordid`clordid xasc

select from( 
        (select column_1, apptype, column_3, from orders where apptype like "CASPER" or "FOO")
         )}each .utl.get_bdts[2017.12.04;2017.12.05]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the `or` statement as follows:

```
select column_1, apptype, column_3, from orders where (apptype like "CASPER") or apptype like "FOO"
```

The parenthesis surrounding (apptype like "CASPER") ensure that a length error is not thrown due to the fact that q will read the clause from right to left.

Comment: Thank you - do you know any resources to learn kdb - sample queries etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`any`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/logic/#any) and [each right `/:`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-right) to include multiple terms instead of `or`:

```
select column_1, apptype, column_3 from orders where any apptype like/:("CASPER";"FOO")
```

The advantage of this is that it is quite easy to extend for more than 2 terms.

In your example above `"CASPER" or "FOO"` is being evaluated first which is resulting in a `'length` error.

Example:

```
q)show tab:([]a:1 2 3;b:`CASPER`FOO`BAR)
a b
--------
1 CASPER
2 FOO
3 BAR
q)select from tab where any b like/:("CASPER";"FOO")
a b
--------
1 CASPER
2 FOO
```

Comment: This answer is so much better than the accepted. Not only is it more efficient, it's more q-like which speaks to the entire purpose of vector-based languages